# Windows DHCP not showing the accurate leases

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp, dhcp-server

In Windows System Event log, there are DHCP server warnings that IP address range of a scope (10.40.0.0) that available is low.

##### Windows Event Log

[image]

But in the DHCP program, the Address Leases is only showing 4 or 5 leases. Based on the settings it should allow 235 leases in total.

##### DHCP Address Leases DHCP scope properties

[image]

[image]

There is only 4 for reservation.
[image]

Is it the Windows System Event log warning is inaccurate? Or is it the DHCP program's Address Leases inaccurate? How do I resolve this to see accurate information?

This is in a Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Please check network mask for that DHCP scope.

Comment: Hi @ZoranJankov are you referring to check the Subnet mask? I added a screenshot of the Subnet mask, what should I check in there?

Comment: Hi @Boon Chye Phang! Yes I was referring to the subnet mask. I thought you accidentally put wrong subnet mask, but it is fine. What about your address reservations? Check if you have any. They will count as leased addresses.

Comment: Hi @ZoranJankov, I have checked there is only 4 IPs for reservation. Added the screenshot of it too.

Answer (score 2):

`Is it the Windows System Event log warning is inaccurate?`

No the event log is accurate. 27 days ago on October 21 that was the status of the DHCP scope available leases.

Comment: Hi Greg, the screenshots of the DHCP address lease was also taken around the time, that is why I cannot understand why the lease is only a few. Do you have any idea why?